# React Native button click region/area

Tags: css, reactjs, native

I am attempting to make some buttons on a react application by using touchable opacity. However I am finding an issue when I try and size the button, for instance: when I set the width of the button, the entire left and right to the end of the screen remains clickable even though the button is a much smaller region. Same happens if I try and add a margin, it'll set the vertical click zone above and below the button clickable for that corresponding margin amount.

```
<View style={styles.button}>
        <View style={[{backgroundColor: props.color}, {height: 100},
        {width: "70%"}, {margin: 10}]}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{props.text}</Text>
    </View>
        </View>
)
return<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>{content}</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default every element has alignSelf set as 'stretch'. Add see if changing it to 'flex-start' helps.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however when I tried doing this I still found the same issue.

Comment: @Layken or just set the width directly on the TouchableOpacity Element

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react native version >= 0.63, then use Pressable component instead. It's more powerful, it provide hitSlop prop to adjust the pressable area of the button.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable